# Order 2D Arrays based on a sum of each row in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

The questions pretty much sums it up. Here's what I have so far:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int sum1;
    int sum2;
    int sum3;
    int sum4;
    int sum5;
    int sum6;
    int sum7;
    int sum8;

    int a[8][7] = {
        { 2, 4, 3, 4, 5, 8, 8 } ,
        { 7, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4 } ,
        { 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2 } ,
        { 9, 3, 4, 7, 3, 4, 1 } ,
        { 3, 5, 4, 3, 6, 3, 8 } ,
        { 3, 4, 4, 6, 3, 4, 4 } ,
        { 3, 7, 4, 8, 3, 8, 4 } ,
        { 6, 3, 5, 9, 2, 7, 9 }
    };

    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {

    }
}
```

I'm planning on assigning the sum of each value from sum1 to sum8 to a row, then order each row by its total sum and display it to the user.

However, I keep getting stuck and can't find any good documentation. Can anyone help me write an effective function I can loop through in my for loop to add each of the rows to a sum, then return the sum and average all the rows out? (this will likely have to be more than one function but...whatever.)

Comment: Really? You couldn't find a good documentation? So what documentation were you looking?

Comment: If I understand it correctly, for each row you want the sum and the average. So, just like `a`, your `sum` can be an array too `int sum[8]`. Then, inside the `for` you showed, for each row in your array you can calculate the sum of that row (using another for)... and keep the value on the variable `sum[i]`. Afterwards, since you know the sum of each row, you can calculate the average by dividing it by the amount of columns (8). If you want to order based on the sum, I would suggest using a vector of `std::vector` and the method `std::sort` with your own customized  `compare` method.

Comment: Turn into `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`,  use `std::sort` with a lambda in which you calculate two sums with `std::accumulate` and compare them. Done.

Comment: I was looking at some of the previous questions about 2d arrays in C++. None of them wanted to do precisely what I'm trying to do here, so I figured I ask. Guess that makes me a huge douche with 5 downvotes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the sum of each row displayed in ascending order, the following code will do that...

```
// #include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int sums[8] = {0};

    int a[8][7] = {
        { 2, 4, 3, 4, 5, 8, 8 } ,
        { 7, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4 } ,
        { 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2 } ,
        { 9, 3, 4, 7, 3, 4, 1 } ,
        { 3, 5, 4, 3, 6, 3, 8 } ,
        { 3, 4, 4, 6, 3, 4, 4 } ,
        { 3, 7, 4, 8, 3, 8, 4 } ,
        { 6, 3, 5, 9, 2, 7, 9 }
    };

    // calculate the sums
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            sums[i] += a[i][j];
        }
    }

    sort(begin(sums), end(sums)); // sort the sums

    copy(begin(sums), end(sums), ostream_iterator<int>(cout, " ")); // display the sums

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you are a cool programmer. You do not seek an easy way.

Of course you could use an array of sums but it seems it is too easy.

Well, then try the following

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>

int main()
{
    int sum1;
    int sum2;
    int sum3;
    int sum4;
    int sum5;
    int sum6;
    int sum7;
    int sum8;

    int a[8][7] = {
        { 2, 4, 3, 4, 5, 8, 8 } ,
        { 7, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4 } ,
        { 3, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2, 2 } ,
        { 9, 3, 4, 7, 3, 4, 1 } ,
        { 3, 5, 4, 3, 6, 3, 8 } ,
        { 3, 4, 4, 6, 3, 4, 4 } ,
        { 3, 7, 4, 8, 3, 8, 4 } ,
        { 6, 3, 5, 9, 2, 7, 9 }
    };


    size_t i = 0;
    for ( auto p : { &sum1, &sum2, &sum3, &sum4, &sum5, &sum6, &sum7, &sum8 } )
    {
        *p = std::accumulate( a[i], a[i] + 7, 0 );
        ++i;
    }

    for ( int x : { sum1, sum2, sum3, sum4, sum5, sum6, sum7, sum8 } ) std::cout << x << std::endl;
}
```

The output is

```
34
28
20
31
32
28
37
41
```

Having the sums you can find any average. I hope you will do this yourself.